# Google Calendar Events wordpress plugin previous / next month buttons not working

Tags: calendar, wordpress

I know this question should better be addressed to the author of the plugin, but since he doesn't respond I thought I might try my luck here.

I've installed [**Google Calendar Events**](http://wordpress.org/plugins/google-calendar-events/) plugin [**on my wordpress website**](http://kristinaartgallery.ru/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9/), and for some reason, after I click the next month button for the first time, the previous / next month buttons don't work anymore, nothing happens when I click it. To see what I'm talking about go to my website link, click "next month" button and then try clicking previous or next month button – they will not respond.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Thanks in advance!